# Dynamic Mail Merge where data exists

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code:

```
Sub RunMerge()

    Dim wd As Object
    Dim wdocSource As Object
    Dim Last_Row As Integer

    Dim strWorkbookName As String

    Last_Row = Worksheets("_Main").Cells(52, 6).Value

    Const wdFormLetters = 0, wdOpenFormatAuto = 0
    Const wdSendToNewDocument = 0, wdDefaultFirstRecord = 1, wdDefaultLastRecord = -16

    On Error Resume Next
    Set wd = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If wd Is Nothing Then
        Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set wdocSource = wd.Documents.Open("C:\Users\eviera\Desktop\CertificateTemplate\CertificateTemplate_Re-entryV1.docx")

    strWorkbookName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name

    wdocSource.MailMerge.MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters

    wdocSource.MailMerge.OpenDataSource _
            Name:=strWorkbookName, _
            AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
            Revert:=False, _
            Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, _
            Connection:="Data Source=" & strWorkbookName & ";Mode=Read", _
            SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `_Main$`"

    With wdocSource.MailMerge
        .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
        .SuppressBlankLines = True
        With .DataSource
            .FirstRecord = wdDefaultFirstRecord
            .LastRecord = wdDefaultLastRecord
        End With
        .Execute Pause:=False
    End With

    wd.Visible = True
    wdocSource.Close SaveChanges:=False

    Set wdocSource = Nothing
    Set wd = Nothing

End Sub
```

I have about 50 slots. As I read data (from Excel) to merge with a Word document which generates certificates, I get a lot of empty certificates.

I'm trying to  print the certificates with data. When I attempt to print, it does not allow me to print only say 1-4.

I cannot run the code without declaring constants:
`wdDefaultFirstRecord = 1, wdDefaultLastRecord = -16` Have to remain constant values

```
With wdocSource.MailMerge
    .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
    .SuppressBlankLines = True
    With .DataSource
        .FirstRecord = wdDefaultFirstRecord
        .LastRecord = wdDefaultLastRecord
    End With
```

I tried to force the last record to be read from a cell to determine the last record. To no avail, it provides an empty certificate on top then only displays one record on word.

I want the program to read fields with data, not the empty slots.